# Cookies aren't firing when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fire a cookie saving the persons first name when a button is clicked. And then show the cookie when the read cookie button is clicked.

However, the cookie doesn't seem to be saving?

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="fname" value="First name"><br />
    <input type="text" id="lname" value="Last name">
</form>

<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Cookie" />
<input id="btnRead" type="button" value="Read Cookie" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#fname").click(function () {
            $.cookie("Name", $("#fname").val());
        });
        $("#btnRead").click(function () {
            alert($.cookie("Name"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: 1) Basic first step: Do you have any errors in the browser's Console? Or do you get some other unexpected result? "doesn't seem to" is not a useful piece of information and suggests to me that you haven't done much to investigate this or debug your code. Either that or you need to get into the habit of giving more precise descriptions of your problem. N.B. `$.cookie` is not part of core jQuery - it would require an extra plugin...have you loaded that plugin in your page? If not you'll definitely get a Console error when you try to use the `$.cookie` function

Comment: 2) `$("#fname").click` doesn't make a lot of sense - why would you want to save the cookie as soon as the user clicks on the textbox? That means it will save before they even have chance to start typing. And currrently your "Add Cookie" button doesn't do anything at all. Maybe you meant to write `$("#btnAdd").click` instead of `$("#fname").click`?

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" id="fname" value="First name"><br />
    <input type="text" id="lname" value="Last name">
</form>

<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Cookie" />
<input id="btnRead" type="button" value="Read Cookie" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            $.cookie("Name", $("#fname").val());
        });
        $("#btnRead").click(function () {
            alert($.cookie("Name"));
        });
    });
</script>
```